# What's this tree in Massachusetts?

Tags: identification, trees

This is the closest photo I could get of the leaves (it's a very tall tree). The leaves are large, bright green, and the tree has white flowers. Does anyone recognize it?

[image: Tall tree with large, bright green leaves and white flowers.]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is catalpa. In the midwest , the tradition if to severely prune them to about 10 ft. high so the flowers can be easily seen. When I first saw upruned ones in TX, I couldn't figure out what they were.  I only saw the flowers because I was bird watching and many birds were attracted to insects in the flowers.

Comment: is correct - that's a Catalpa speciosa. I've lived in the Midwest my entire life (Ike was President when I was born), and I have never heard of the tradition that blacksmith mentions - we let our catalpas flourish tall and proud in Wisconsin :)  These is also a Southern species (C. bignoides, or something like that).

Comment: That was the Chicago area

Comment: We were 90 miles apart, yet with such different traditions. Sort of like the differences between the Bears and the Packers, eh? :)

Comment: They were supposed to have great fishing bait worms ( caterpillars) in the flowers, maybe why they were pruned.

Comment: @blacksmith37 Thanks! I've seen several of them here but the lowest branches are really high up!

Comment: Our northern catalpas in Idaho have very visible flowers with no pruning. We don't get caterpillars on them, though, as far as I've seen. I agree that it's some kind of Catalpa.